# unable to fix arrayoutof bound exception

Tags: java

I am getting these errors it's a runtime error; I have no idea why it is happening I tried to find the solution but couldn't find it.
Since I am new in java please help me to find

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 34
>       at UnionAndIntersection.BinarySearch(UnionAndIntersection.java:90)
>       at UnionAndIntersection.BinarySearch(UnionAndIntersection.java:96)
>       at UnionAndIntersection.BinarySearch(UnionAndIntersection.java:100)
>       at UnionAndIntersection.BinarySearch(UnionAndIntersection.java:100)
>       at UnionAndIntersection.BinarySearch(UnionAndIntersection.java:100)
>       at UnionAndIntersection.BinarySearch(UnionAndIntersection.java:100)
>       at UnionAndIntersection.Union(UnionAndIntersection.java:53)
>       at UnionAndIntersection.main(UnionAndIntersection.java:26)

please help me to fix this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

class UnionAndIntersection {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int arr1[]=new int[20];
        int arr2[]=new int[20];
        int m,n,i,j;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter no of elements in first array");
        m=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter no of element of second Array");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Elements in 1st Array");

        for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
            arr1[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter Elements in 2nd Array");
        for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
            arr2[j]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        UnionAndIntersection ui=new UnionAndIntersection();
        ui.Union(arr1,arr2,m,n);
        ui.Intersection(arr1,arr2,m,n);
    }

    void Union(int arr1[],int arr2[],int m,int n) {
        if(m>n) {
            int tempa[]=arr1;
            arr1=arr2;
            arr2=tempa;

            int temp=m;
            m=n;
            n=temp;
        }

   Arrays.sort(arr1);
   for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
    System.out.println(arr1[i]+"");
  }

  for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
    if(BinarySearch(arr1,0,m-1,arr2[i])== -1)
        System.out.println(arr2[i]+"");
   }
   }
  void Intersection(int arr1[],int arr2[],int m,int n)
     {
   if(m>n)
   {
    int tempa[]=arr1;
    arr1=arr2;
    arr2=tempa;

    int temp=m;
    m=n;
    n=temp;

   }


    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
   {
    System.out.println(arr1[i]+"");
   }

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
    if(BinarySearch(arr1,0,m-1,arr2[i])!= -1)
        System.out.println(arr2[i]+"");
   }
   }
   int BinarySearch(int arr[],int l,int h,int x)
   {
    if(h>=1)
    {
        int mid=l+h-1/2;
        if(arr[mid]==x)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if(arr[mid]>x)
        {
            return BinarySearch(arr,l,mid-1,x);
        }
        else{

        return BinarySearch(arr,mid+1,h,x);
        }
    }
    return -1;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the size of the array to 20, not to the user input. If the user puts in a number larger than 20, you get the error.
So change:

```
int arr1[]=new int[20];
int arr2[]=new int[20];
```

to

```
   int arr1[]=new int[m];
    int arr2[]=new int[n];
```

Comment: thanks @Markus it worked ,i really need to work hard